# Is Jenkins plugin support development through gradle broken

Tags: java, gradle, jenkins-plugins

I was building this fine previously but now its broken. I suspect the json-lib:2.4-jenkins-2 is the problem

```
  $:~/java$ gent --http --name=test kiy0taka/jenkins-plugin
  $:~/java$ cd test
  $:~/java/test$ ./gradlew server
```

Output from final command

```
  :localizer
  :stapler FAILED

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':stapler'.
  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
     > Artifact 'org.kohsuke.stapler:json-lib:2.4-jenkins-2@jar' not found.

  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option     to get more log output.

 BUILD FAILED

 Total time: 9.302 secs
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Ok not sure why this is but I removed the cached file

```
rm -fr /home/XXXX/.m2/repository/org/kohsuke/stapler/json-lib/2.4-jenkins-2/json-lib-2.4-jenkins-2.pom
```

and rebuilt with

```
./gradlew server
```

and it worked fine

Comment: I think this is caused by having maven and gradle projects at the same time. Build a maven one then a gradle one and the gradle one fails until you remove this file.